# How to send extra variables in a post from a form?

Tags: php, html

In my php script I have additional variables I don't want visible to the user to be sent in a _post from a  to another php script. How do I do that?

Comment: If on the same server, use a session instead, if on another server, post the data there yourself, get a token for that data, only let the user post that (input type=hidden) token.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Hidden input](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/input/hidden) fields:

```
<input type="hidden" name="var" value="..." />
```

Comment: It should be noted that this method exposes that data to the user, should they look at the page source, and it is also possible that the variables can be circumvented with little effort.  If the data is sensitive, session variables become a necessary alternative.

Comment: The information isn't sensitive so security is not necessary. This method is sufficient. Thank-you.

Answer (score 2):

- use [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) (pros: does not need to be reposted, stays in php between scripts)
- use [input hidden html](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input) fields